# Background problem with type color forms in PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: php, forms, prestashop-1.7

I'm adding an type color "color picker" using helper forms in Ps 1.7, and by default is empty and the field background is background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); added by inline so i can't understand where this comes from and i want to change it to different color when field is empty by default.

```
                array(
                    'type' => 'color',
                    'label' => $this->trans('example'),
                    'name' => 'example',
                    'hint' => $this->trans('example text.'),
                    'class' => 'text-center',
                ),
```

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFYQN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the color picker in the tpl_vars e.g.

```
$helperForm->tpl_vars = array(
     'fields_value' => array(
         'nameofmycolorpicker' => '#3399ff',
     ),
);
```

Comment: Didn't work, it gave me "[2] Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: Can you post your full HelperForm coding?